# can't get css table border to be consistent throughout table and nested table

Tags: html, css, border, border-layout

The first row in my table has three cells.  I'm trying to set up a second row with four cells.  I would like the borders to all be the same.  I cannot, however, achieve that so far as the cells on the bottom row (the row with four cells) either has a double border, or no border. I've tired border-collapse and border-style-right, with no luck.  How can I have the bottom row look just like the top row - with a single 1px border - except 4 cells in stead of three cells?  Here's my code:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
table
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
table.outer
{
    border: 1px black solid;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width:750px;
}
table.outer td
{
    border: 1px black solid;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.nested
{
    width: 750px;
}
table.nested td
{
    border:0px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}   
</style>    
</head>
<body>

<table class="outer">
  <tr>
    <td>foo 1</td>
    <td>foo 2</td>
    <td>foo 3</td>
  </tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <table class="nested">
              <tr>
                <td>bar 1</td>
                <td>bar 2</td>
                <td>bar 3</td>
                <td>bar 4</td>
              </tr> 
            </table>
        </td>   
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason why you must have a nested table? If you want the two rows to look identical, try adding more rows and adjusting the `colspan` of each cell. If you find the least common multiple of both three and four, you can make a table that has twelve columns and set the `colspan` of a row with three columns to four and the `colspan` of a row with four columns to three.

Nesting tables within tables can be problematic with CSS and it is also heavier for the page.

```
<table class="outer">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">foo 1</td>
    <td colspan="4">foo 2</td>
    <td colspan="4">foo 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">bar 1</td> 
    <td colspan="3">bar 2</td>
    <td colspan="3">bar 3</td>
    <td colspan="3">bar 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This way, you can also style all of the cells with just one CSS `td` selector, if you wanted to share a common style between the two rows.

Extra explanation of answer:
(Using the LCM as the total number of columns for the table ensures that each cell can be the same size as the other cells in its row, without affecting the size of cells in other rows. You can make a row with n cells as long as the total number of columns in the table is divisible by n. Thus, with this twelve column wide table, you can have rows with 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 12 columns, and all cells can be centered about the middle of the table. Also, if you want to dynamically generate a table, it wouldn't be too hard to write a function to create however many cells you need in each row with this method.)

Comment: I don't have a good reason beyond i'm gavin trouble getting your solution to look like the solution offered above.

Comment: If you substitute this for just the HTML code that creates the table, and add the `class="outer"` to the table tag (forgot to add this), all of your cells should have the same style regardless of row. You'll probably save a bit of loading time this way and won't have to maintain two separate `td` style. Also, you could add other three or four cells lower in the table without having to worry about nesting.

Comment: Using only one table, you should also be able to remove `border-collapse` from the CSS.

Comment: @dwstein: This is the more efficient way to display the table. The only reason I answered using the nested table is because it was asked in the question. If you add your desired `border` styles to `.outer td` in FlyingMolga's example, it will have the same result. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/nCwLZ/

Comment: @FlyingMolga:  you are correct.  I just didn't understand what you were trying to tell me.  Thanks, also, to JSW189.

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues. First, the `<td>` tags surrounding the nested table should really be `<tr>` tags. Second, the nested table `border` width should be `1px`, not `0px`.

HTML:

```
<table class="outer">
    <tr>
        <td>foo 1</td>
        <td>foo 2</td>
        <td>foo 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr colspan="3">
        <table class="nested">
            <tr>
                <td>bar 1</td>
                <td>bar 2</td>
                <td>bar 3</td>
                <td>bar 4</td>
            </tr> 
        </table>
    </tr>   
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

table.outer {
    border: 1px black solid;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width:750px;
}

table.outer td {
    border: 1px black solid;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.nested {
    width: 750px;
}

table.nested td {
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5D2hN/

Comment: That html is just as invalid.  You need both `<tr>` and `<td>`.